# returning array after promises within loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, angular-promise

I am trying to aggregate the responses after running a loop and having promises being called each time. However, the function does not wait for all the promises to be done and returns undefined.

```
getAllPluginImpls(): DesktopPluginDefinitionImpl[] {
    let pluginArray: DesktopPluginDefinitionImpl[] = [];
    let promises = [];
    Array.from(this.pluginMap.keys()).forEach(id =>
      promises.push(this.pluginManager.findPluginDefinition(id).then(
        def => {
          console.log("id");
          console.log(id);
          console.log("def");
          console.log(def);
          let pluginImpl = def as DesktopPluginDefinitionImpl;
          pluginArray.push(pluginImpl);
        }
      )
    )
    );
    Promise.all(promises).then(s => {
      console.log("end reached :(");
      console.log(pluginArray);
      return pluginArray;
    });

  }
```

Comment: You need to return your promise.

Comment: Use .`map()`, not `.forEach()`

Comment: Instead of pushing to an array, return the value from your promise and `Promise.all()` will give you what you want.

Comment: yes but i want to ultimately return the array

Comment: You need to return a promise of the array.

Comment: @user633183 that's assuming `.keys()` returns an array and not an iterator object like [`Map#keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should be returning `Promise<DesktopPluginDefinitionImpl[]>`, and secondly as pointed out in comments, the complexity of your method would be greatly simplified by avoiding usage of `.forEach()` to `.push()` entries into a scoped array.

```
getAllPluginImpls(): Promise<DesktopPluginDefinitionImpl[]> {
  const pluginArray: Promise<DesktopPluginDefinitionImpl>[] = Array.from(
    this.pluginMap.keys(),
    id => this.pluginManager.findPluginDefinition(id)
  );

  return Promise.all(pluginArray);
}
```

And to clarify, the `Promise<DesktopPluginDefinitionImpl>[]` is *not* a typo. `Promise.all()` converts an array of promises into a promise of an array.